# How do I give variables value with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am very new to this so I can imagine this looks terrible. My problems start at line 43. I've taken bits of different code I found to start learning. I haven't been able to find answers on kivy like I have about python.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Calc>:
    # This are attributes of the class Calc now
    a: _a
    b: _b
    c: _c
    d: _d
    e: _e
    result: _result
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    Label:
                        text: 'Grats'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _a
                    Label:
                        text: 'Alcohol Sales'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _b
                    Label:
                        text: 'Food Sales'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _c
                    Label:
                        id: _result
                    TextInput:
                        id: _d
                        text: '0.06'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _e
                        text: '0.05'
                    Button:
                        text: 'sum'
                        # You can do the opertion directly
                        on_press: _result.text = int(_a.text) - (str(int(root.b)) * int(float(root.d.text)) + str(int(root.c)) * int(float(root.e.text))
                    Button:
                        text: 'product'
                        # Or you can call a method from the root class (instance of calc)
                        on_press: root.product(*args)
                     
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                Label: 
                    text: 'The second screen'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 1'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 2'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen2'""")

class Calc(FloatLayout):
    # define the multiplication of a function
    def product(self, instance):
        # self.result, self.a and self.b where defined explicitely in the kv
        self.result.text = int(_a.text) - (str(int(self.b.text) * int(self.d.text)))
        

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I have a similar app running with just python that works out gratuity. I would like to add a GUI to that but I can't get the maths part to work.

Answer (score 0):

For correct coding you need to control textinputs. Because if user pass any of it , program gets failure.But examine my code and see that how can you fix your error in your .kv codes.You need to improve your code. Good luck.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
Builder.load_string("""
<Calc>:
    # This are attributes of the class Calc now
    a: _a
    b: _b
    c: _c
    d: _d
    e: _e
    result: _result
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    Label:
                        text: 'Grats'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _a
                    Label:
                        text: 'Alcohol Sales'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _b
                    Label:
                        text: 'Food Sales'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _c
                    Label:
                        id: _result
                    TextInput:
                        id: _d
                        text: '0.06'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _e
                        text: '0.05'
                    Button:
                        text: 'sum'
                        on_press: _result.text = str(float(_a.text)-float(_b.text)*float(_d.text)+float(_c.text)*float(_e.text))
                    Button:
                        text: 'product'
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                Label: 
                    text: 'The second screen'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 1'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 2'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen2'""")
class Calc(FloatLayout):
    def product(self, instance):
        pass #For improve, you need to use ObjectProperty for check textinputs.
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calc()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It always seems so simple when it's out in front of you. Is there a way to define '0.06' and '0.05' without having to make them an input?

Comment: Add this code below both textinputs in .kv file: `disabled: True`. Also, you can change these textinputs to Label or remove these widgets and add only these floats to your math operation directly. As you wish.